# Loop through properties in a generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I find the properties that a generic contains and loop through them?

```
class Foo {
  bar: number;
  thing: string;

  static jsonToFoo(json: any): Foo {
    return jsonToWidget<Foo>(json);
  }
}

function jsonToWidget<T>(json: any): T {
  const values: any[] = [];

  for (const key in T) { //  <---- this is invalid
    if (json[key]) {
      values.push(json[key]);
    }
  }

  return new (<any> this.constructor)(...values) as T;
}

const newFoo: Foo = jsonToFoo({bar: 1, thing: 'foobar'});
```

This is an approximate reproduction. I want to be able to loop through whatever T contains, in this case `bar` and `thing`, to create a new Foo with the Json values.

Comment: Given TS is vanished from runtime I believe that's impossible. Given how many `any` and `as` you have here, you don't benefit from having it "typed" anyway.

Comment: Yeah at first I understood wrong but now I see the problem here - definitely not seeing how you're going to get "T" at run time, no way. I am sure there is a fancy TypeScript way to do it though, you just have to know under the hood they are going to do what is necessary for it to work at run time, like with TypeScript enums, there's no such thing at run time.

At the end of the day I think you will need a const object initialized with the keys needed to loop through.

Then I would use for(var key of Object.keys(obj)) to loop through them.

Comment: Actually - thinking more on this - if T is a class I haven't messed with just trying to do new T() and if a default constructor could work to give you an object to loop over... Might have to implement default values in the constructor though, not sure...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in this case maintaining your own const objects for this purpose, initialized with default/null values. This just isn't a TypeScript issue, although there may be a nice fancy solution TypeScript provides in the compiler.

At the end of the day, to loop through object keys at run time, you'll need an object initialized at run time (maybe typescript will put that in your output code for you). You could spend time trying to figure out if TypeScript has some nice way to do that under the hood for you, or you can just go ahead and do what you know is needed.

I might maintain a list of const objects for this purpose in it's own scope, and have a function to get the object by name. In your generic function you'd need to know at run time what object you're working on (pass a key or something) - then call the function to get the object to loop over. Or something like that...